# Не работает клиент еррор после добавления commands.has_any_roles

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

добавил я.`@commands.has_any_role(819292703589269514,817408828500213860,817408830240456754)` и предупреждение об ошибке перестало работать, хотя когда это было `@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)` все работало, в чем проблема, вот код

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_any_role(819292703589269514,817408828500213860,817408830240456754,817643991331766283)
async def clear (ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
    emb = discord.Embed (title = 'Удалено {} сообщений!'.format(amount), colour = discord.Color.gold())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=30)


@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance (error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ошибка", colour = discord.Color.gold())
        embed.add_field(name='Обязательно укажите аргумент', value='Пример: .clear 10 (от 1 до 100)', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=30)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ошибка", colour = discord.Color.gold())
        embed.add_field(name='У вас нет прав модератора', value='Обратитесь к модераторам', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

По причине того, что `has_any_role` [вызывает другое исключение](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role): `commands.MissingAnyRole`.